# How to sort lazy-loaded entities, using entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework's code-first method. I've got two entities, with a one to many relation between them.

My question, is there a way to configure a table to always sort a certain way, so that I do not have to explicitly say I want to sort by something in the query via an `OrderBy`?

Comment: 1. Vote for it to be supported out of the box https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/121

Comment: 2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/02/25/tip-1-sorting-relationships-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `DbSet<T>` as `IQueryable<T>`

```
public IQueryable<MyEntity> MyEntities
{
  get{ return this.Set<MyEntity>().OrderBy(t => t.Column); }
}
```

the only problem is that you will affect every single query from performance perspective even when is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about reconfiguring the table, but you could always do something like that in your `DbContext` file. You could have an `IQueryable` of whatever type you're looking at which would return the corresponding `DbSet` except ordered exactly as you want it.